# p-value to Z-statistic for a KS test

Tags: normal-distribution, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, z-score

Say you had a two tailed normal distribution `A` for some dataset, and you then measured the probability that some set of data points `B` were drawn from `A`, using a [KS test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO2RmSkXK3c).

Could someone explain to me the process by which you would convert the p-value returned by the KS test into a Z score? (No matter how outlandish or silly the reasoning for doing so)

I realise the first thing you would do is look at a Z table but I'm interested here in knowing how you go about doing the conversion explicitly.

---

Here is my current understanding/interpretation of how to do this:

- I understand that the p-value gives you the area under a normal distribution from a position N$\sigma $ away from the mean, outwards.
- If I understand correctly the Z value is the number of $\sigma$ away from the mean you are at any position along the x axis in a 1D Normal distribution. Therefore, here, N = Z.

A pictorial representation of the above points:

[image]

- So my approach for getting Z given a p-value would be to integrate the normal equation and solve for the lower limit. Then dividing through by $\sigma$ will leave you with Z. Is that correct?
- So integrate:

  $\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right)^2\right) dx$

  and solve for `a`, given that the integral should equal the p-value.

---

However, is there a simpler, better way to do this given that the KS test returns a d-statistic using the cumulative distribution from your data? Perhaps because of that there is a neat trick to make a simpler conversion that I cannot yet understand?

Many thanks for any help in this matter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution.  Because your understanding of the p-value is incorrect, check out our [posts on p-values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bp-value%5d%20score%3a10).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you give me a little pointer as to what specifically is incorrect in my understanding of the p-value? I've seen it as the area under a normal distribution when calculating z-scores many times and interpret it as a likelihood (rather than a probability) of drawing samples from a region given some assumption such as the mean of the distribution being true from which the sample is drawn under. I don't understand the Wikipedia article section that you've pointed to I'm sorry-  just because it's a little too die hard for me to understand.

Comment: Extra: To be more specific, I've always interpreted the p-value from a KS test as the likelihood of drawing a sample "at least as extreme as" what is being seen when compared to some other distribution. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: (1) The KS test does not "measure the probability that some set of data points were drawn from [another set]." This issue is the topic of the highest-voted threads on p-values. (2) The distribution of the KS statistic is not Normal, so areas under the Normal curve are irrelevant.  That's the topic of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: A KS test measures the likelihood of drawing samples at least as extreme as the ones being looked at in reference to some proposed underlying distribution no? That's what I read in all texts on the test. But yes for (2) that makes sense as it's a comparison of cdf's but if you are absolutely certain the underlying distribution of the comparison distribution is normal, would it not make logical sense that there could be a conversion to something like a z statistic under that very strict axiom? Thanks again for replying by the way!